# Look ahead until a value is hit and record the max high

Tags: r

If I have something like this:

```
v <- c(2.00, 1.75, 3.00, 1.00, 2.00, 1.00, 2.00, 1.50)
```

For every row, I would like to essentially look ahead and see how high it gets (what is the max) before it comes down and hits a certain number. In this case that certain number is 1.00. I would like to have results for every index.

Expected results from above:

```
[1] 3.00 3.00 3.00 2.00 2.00 2.00 2.00
```

cummax() is great but it keeps increasing for the entire history of content. I would like it to reset once a certain hardcoded number is hit.

Thanks!

Comment: Given vector `v`, does `cummax(v)[v == v[1] - 1]` give you what you want?

Comment: @RitchieSacramento I updated the description to hopefully be more clear.

Comment: Why is the last value in the result `1.50` and not `2.00`?

Comment: @GregorThomas You are correct, the last one would be 2.00.

Answer (score 0):

```
v <- c(2.00, 1.75, 3.00, 1.00, 2.00, 1.00, 2.00, 1.50)
library(dplyr)
df = data.frame(v) %>%
  group_by(g = cumsum(v == 1)) %>%
  mutate(result = max(v)) %>%
  ungroup()
df
# # A tibble: 8 × 3
#       v     g result
#   <dbl> <int>  <dbl>
# 1  2        0      3
# 2  1.75     0      3
# 3  3        0      3
# 4  1        1      2
# 5  2        1      2
# 6  1        2      2
# 7  2        2      2
# 8  1.5      2      2
```